# Unable to insert posixlt datetime into dataframe

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct, posixlt

This is my data frame structure

> str(data10180619_Draft_input_temp)
>   Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   347 obs. of  2 variables:
>    $ DATE      : Date, format: "2019-03-01" "2019-03-04" "2019-03-04" "2019-03-05" ...
>    $ ENTRY_TIME: POSIXlt, format: "2019-03-01 09:30:08" "2019-03-04 09:30:09" "2019-03-04 09:37:06" "2019-03-05 09:31:14" ...

I'm trying to insert a row into the data frame, I'm able to populate the DATE, but the ENTRY_TIME is giving me errors

> data10180619_Draft_input_temp[nrow(data10180619_Draft_input_temp)+1,]<-c("2019-09-29",as.POSIXlt.character("09:30:02",format = '%H:%M:%S',origin="2019-09-29"))
>   Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, nrow(data10180619_Draft_input_temp) +  :
>     provided 12 variables to replace 2 variables

I'd like the date portion of the posixlt (ENTRY_TIME) to be the same as the date populated in DATE column

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to answer your question with a sample of your data. And make sure to format your code as code. The value passed to origin has to be a date, currently it's a string. Try this:

```r
data10180619_Draft_input_temp[nrow(data10180619_Draft_input_temp)+1,] <-as.POSIXlt.character("09:30:02",
                                                                                             format = '%H:%M:%S',
                                                                                             origin=ymd("2019-09-29"))
```

Comment: Thanks, But the origin stays the same as sysdate I wanted the date portion to be set as in the origin